# Mediator configuration issues. Unable to configure it correctly

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I was just working on my project on .NET core using the Mediator Pattern. I created a get() method in a controller which would be further being processed by query and query handler to provide the result from DataBase.
Following is my code:

UserContoller.cs:

```
namespace ClaimTrackingSystem.Controllers.UserManager
{
    [Route("api/user")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public UsersController(ApplicationDBContext context, IMediator mediator)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        // GET: api/Users
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAllUser()
        {
            var query = new GetAllUserQuery();
            var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

GetAllUserQuery.cs:

```
namespace ClaimTrackingSystem.Queries
{
    public class GetAllUserQuery : IRequest<List<UserDTO>>
    {
        public GetAllUserQuery()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

GetAllUsersQueryHandler.cs:

```
namespace ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers
{
    public class GetAllUserQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAllUserQuery, List<UserDTO>>
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public GetAllUserQueryHandler(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }
        public async Task<List<UserDTO>> Handle(GetAllUserQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return (List<UserDTO>)await _userRepository.GetAllUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
namespace ClaimTrackingSystem
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureSqlServerContext(Configuration);
            services.ConfigureCors();
            services.ConfigureIISIntegration();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAllUserQuery).Assembly);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace ClaimTrackingSystem
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

repository.cs:

```
namespace UserService.Data.Repository
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

        public UserRepository(ApplicationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUser()
        {
            return (IEnumerable<User>)await _context.User.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        Task<IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.User>> IUserRepository.GetAllUser()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

dto.cs:

```
namespace UserService.Application.DTOs
{
    public class UserDTO
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Guid Role { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

While running this progect in VS I am getting the following error in Program.cs file inside `main()`  method:

```
System.AggregateException :  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[ClaimTrackingSystem.Queries.GetAllUserQuery,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserService.Application.DTOs.UserDTO]]. Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers.GetAllUserQueryHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'UserService.Domain.Interfaces.IUserRepository' while attempting to activate 'ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers.GetAllUserQueryHandler'.)
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

 Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[ClaimTrackingSystem.Queries.GetAllUserQuery,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserService.Application.DTOs.UserDTO]] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers.GetAllUserQueryHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'UserService.Domain.Interfaces.IUserRepository' while attempting to activate 'ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers.GetAllUserQueryHandler'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'UserService.Domain.Interfaces.IUserRepository' while attempting to activate 'ClaimTrackingSystem.QueryHandlers.GetAllUserQueryHandler'.
```

I hope the information is complete please let me know in case of any other information required. Please help me this this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your repositories implementations to the Dependency Injection container in the `ConfigureServices` of your `Startup` class so that they can be properly injected.

Now you have added your controllers (with `AddControllers`), your `IMapper` (with `AddAutoMapper`) and your `MediatR` related classes such as `GetAllUserQueryHandler` (with `AddMediatR`).

However, `GetAllUserQueryHandler` has a dependency on `IUserRepository` which you haven't added to the container, and therefore the DI library can't create an instance of `GetAllUserQueryHandler` because it doesn't know how to instantiate the dependency `IUserRepository`.

Try the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
// This method gets called by the runtime.
// Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureSqlServerContext(Configuration);
    services.ConfigureCors();
    services.ConfigureIISIntegration();
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetAllUserQuery).Assembly);

    // Add this. Should be Scoped lifetime in this case,
    // but check the docs for getting familiar with the other lifetime alternatives
    services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
}
```

For more information check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked. Could we please have a session on google meet? If you have time I would get some guidance in that.

Comment: @Prakhar no sorry, but that's not an option are you getting the same error though as the original post? I am pretty sure you shouldn't. Update your question if the situation has changed

Comment: My Nuget package was not responding. It worked fine after system restart. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Prakhar glad it worked :) you are welcome